# Method generic return java class

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, casting

I am building generic methods for queries to the database with Hibernate, the following method consults the information of an entity by primary key.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "UnitPers")
private EntityManager entity;

public Object findByPk(Class clazz, Object pk) throws Exception {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = entity().find(clazz, pk);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

This method works correctly, but I do not want to make a cast (object to myTypeEntity) when making the call.

```
private myTypeEntity entity;    
entity = (myTypeEntity) findByPk(myTypeEntity.class, new Bigdecimal("1"));

//GET and SET Methods
```

I want to avoid doing the cast when calling this method, bearing in mind that it is one of the purposes of the generic, but I have not managed to do it, any ideas? or what I intend to do is not possible.

Comment: If you want to use an existing framework for that , have a look at spring data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics instead of using Object:

```
public <T> T findByPk(Class<T> clazz, Object pk) throws Exception {
    T obj = null;
    try {
        obj = entity().find(clazz, pk);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And then it should work without doing the cast

```
private myTypeEntity entity;    
entity = findByPk(myTypeEntity.class, new Bigdecimal("1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

By introducing a generic type variable on the method level you can define what type should be returned, this can be seen in [@cpr4t3s'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847575/5515060) answer.

You can also shorten his snippet to the following:

```
public <T> T findByPk(Class<T> clazz, Object pk) throws Exception {
    return entity().find(clazz, pk);
}
```

Because:

1. You're just throwing the exception up in the `catch`-block
2. You're doing nothing, but return the `obj`-variable

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm still a novice. I'll put into practice. regards